# Facebook Share API - options for "link"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm struggling to create my first Facebook share feature on a website and the issue is a dynamically created link.  I'm trying to share a referal link to (i.e. come checkout ecommerce site and get $20 back).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#share_button').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   FB.ui(
   {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Want $20 off Sailormade bracelets for summer? Shop now and thank me later',
    link: '<?php echo $this->getReferrerLink();?>',
    picture:'http://shop.sailormadeusa.com/media/wysiwyg/raf/refer_a_friend_static_block.jpg'
});
});
});
```

First timer on the Facebook app, and first timer posting here on stackoverflow.  Go easy on me, and let me know if I can provide any additional information.  THanks!

Comment: Yes, you can provide the problem you are having ;)

Comment: So what are you struggling with?

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem is that the link being rendered by the PHP doesn't render.  It strips the link out entirely and actually makes the link the image URL.

Comment: I determined the solution
    link: '<?php echo $this->helper('awraf')->getReferrerLink();?>',